# PHP array: orderID with multiple orderdetailIDs

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs

After receiving data from my db I put this data in an array row by row so I can access this array with al the required data later on. But I'm currently using following array:

**JSON SAMPLE**

```
[{"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle Hofman","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":4,"productTitle":"The Virgin","productPrijs":3.2,"aantal":1,"extras":false,"extrasPrice":0},

{"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle Hofman","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":5,"productTitle":"Sexy Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":3,"extras":false,"extrasPrice":0}]
```

As you can see I got 2 times orderID (5) with each time the orderdetails which all belong to the same orderID, in this example orderID 5.

Now this array isn't great because when using angular I have difficulties showing the orders per orderID and the orderdetails which belong to that orderID.

What I want to show is for each orderID:

is something like: foreach orderdetailID in orderID.

orderID 5 => all of its orderDetails (= data of orderdetailID 4 AND orderdetailID 5)

So when creating that array, how can I add an array of orderdetails to the row of the correspondent orderID?

**example**:

```
[{"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle Hofman","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare", {"orderdetailID":4,"productTitle":"The Virgin","productPrijs":3.2,"aantal":1,"extras":false,"extrasPrice":0},{"orderdetailID":5,"productTitle":"Sexy Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":3,"extras":false,"extrasPrice":0}]
```

Comment: You need to loop over it and create a nested structure. Id probably do this on the PHP side but you could do it on the JS side if you wanted.

Comment: Yes I know I have to loop over it but I can't figure out how to create the desired array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over it and create a nested structure. Id probably do this on the PHP side but you could do it on the JS side if you wanted

```
$orders = array();

// lets create an array of the keys that belong to the "order"
// we will use this to extract the other keys for the details
$orderKeys = array('orderID', 'customerID', 'customerName', 'orderDate', 'orderDeliveryDate', 'orderStatus');
$orderKeys = array_combine($orderKeys, $orderKeys);

// loop over each row in the db result set - not sure
// what driver you are using so you can replace this loop
// with whatever kind of loop makes sense
foreach($resultSet as $row) {
   $id = $row['orderID'];

   if (!isset($orders[$id]) {
      // this is the first record in our result set for this
      // orderID, so lets get the data for the order and put it
      // into the orders array, using the orderID as the array key
      $orders[$id] = array_intersect_key($row,$orderKeys);

      // lets also add an array for all our details items
      // you could use a key other than details just depends on what
      // you want to call it
      $orders[$id]['details'] = array();
   }

   // add the detail item to the order
   $orders[$id]['details'][] = array_diff_key($row, $orderKeys);
}

// create the JSON - use array_values to reindex the array
// since using the orderID as the key is not relevant on the JS side
$ordersJSON = json_encode(array_values($orders));

// now do whatever you need to do with the JSON
```

Comment: I edited a bit but this lead me to the right solution! Thanks a lot